# Changing Directory in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a bash script which should go in a specific directory.
The Problem is that the Script wont go in the newest Folder.

The Folder looks like:

```
root@raspberry ~/jdownloader/logs # ls -lha
total 104K
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:18 1479843940152_Tue, Nov 22, 2016 20.45 +0100
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:21 1480501204839_Wed, Nov 30, 2016 11.20 +0100
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:22 1480501242752_Wed, Nov 30, 2016 11.20 +0100
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:30 1480501308071_Wed, Nov 30, 2016 11.21 +0100
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 30 11:56 1480503116574_Wed, Nov 30, 2016 11.51 +0100
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  12K Nov 23 11:25 extracting
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  64K Nov 30 11:22 updatehistory
```

The Important Snippet from my Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare dir=/var/log/scriptlog/jdstate
declare dir2=~/jdownloader/logs
NewFolder=`ls -rt1 ~/jdownloader/logs -I extracting -I updatehistory | tail -1 > /var/log/scriptlog/jdstate/newfolder.log`
OutputNewFolder=`head $dir/newfolder.log -n 1`
cd\ "\"$dir2/$OutputeNewFolder\""
```

When I try to run the script it shows me the error that it can't find the directory.
But when I copy/paste it, it will go to the Directory.
Any idea how it is possible to go to the directory?

Comment: why is there a backslash after cd? and why are you escaping double quotes?

Comment: I just tried to escape the space( ) after the cd

But it didnt effected anything

Comment: I think you have too many escapes, you don't want literal quotes as part of your `cd` and you don't want to escape the space I don't think.  Try `cd "$dir2/$OutputNewFolder"` (also, spell OutputNewFolder correctly--you have an extra `e`).  Also, see [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/bash-cd-to-the-most-recently-modified-child-directory) on the U&L site

Comment: Thanks to Eric, 

I triedVarious things but forgot the easiest try ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every one how is searching for an Answer:

this is my latest code snippet wich worked gladly for me

```
#!/bin/bash
declare dir=/var/log/scriptlog/jdstate
declare dir2=~/jdownloader/logs
NewFolder=`ls -rt1 ~/jdownloader/logs -I extracting -I updatehistory |  tail -1 > /var/log/scriptlog/jdstate/newfolder.log`
OutputNewFolder=`head $dir/newfolder.log -n 1`
cd "$dir2/$OutputNewFolder"
```

I´m sure the can be improvements for the newest folder but htis works just finde for me

Comment: Seems like a roundabout way to write: `OutputNewFolder=$( ls ... | tail -1)`.